# Google Ads API -- OfflineUserDataJob status: Success but Segment Size on UI: 0

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to upload around 8 million users to Google Ads using Google Ads API (OfflineUserDataJob).

On UI, I see that my upload is successful with match rate (91%~100%). It took around 1-2 hours for the OfflineUserDataJob status change from RUNNING --> SUCCESS

But I can't see the Segment size change on UI (Audience Manager tab)

I read document that is https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/remarketing/audience-types/customer-match?hl=en#customer_match_considerations . I understand that it may take up to 24hours, but I can't seem to find the status "In Progress" on Google Ads UI

Is 24hours apply between status SUCCESS and update Segment size on UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a similar case is answered on the Google Ads API forum (https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/8a2RAJacDfE/m/g1J_TsMuAgAJ).

I quote: The campaigns would be using pre-update snapshots to deliver ads. Once the creating/updating user list completes, then a new list in which ads will be delivered.